# Have command line available upon running Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I just can't seem to find exactly how to have a command line available when starting a Dockerfile. Is there a certain parameter I can set inside the Dockerfile which will give a command line upon starting the image within a Docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah it is a very simple solution

```
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run a container you can add option `-it`

```
docker run -it some/image:tag
```

From [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground):

`For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use -i -t together in order to allocate a tty for the container process. -i -t is often written -it as you’ll see in later examples. Specifying -t is forbidden when the client is receiving its standard input from a pipe, as in`